# python regular how to match a dot with Letter?

Tags: python, regex

i want match string like :

```
what.are you doing?
```

match when behind a dot have some letter
**and replace the "." with ". "**

result like :
`what. are you doing?`

**more example**

input

```
uh....i don't know
```

output

```
uh.... i don't know
```

input

```
do you know....that thing?
```

output

```
do you know.... that thing?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should fit your case:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\S)\.(?=\w)', '. ', s)
```

This uses a positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=...)` that checks if the dot is preceded by a non-space character `\S`. The positive lookbehind assertion `(?=\w)` checks if the dot is followed by a alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty late on this. Though, wanted to share another option:

```
re.sub(r'\.(\w)', '. \\1', s)

Explanation:
\.(\w)
|   |
|   ----> catch an alphabet letter in group '()' which is referenced later in replacement by \\1 (because it's 1st caught group)
escape '.'
```

Hope it helps :)